# Problem connecting to Laravel Websockets from React Native

Tags: javascript, laravel, react-native, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm having problems with Laravel Websockets. I build a chat app using Laravel Websockets, Vue.JS and Laravel-Echo. The web app works correctly, so I started working in a Mobile version with React Native, but I can't connect to private/presence channels.

I can connect to public channels withour problems. I have the following code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            key: 'pusher-app-key',
            cluster: 'mt1',
            wsHost: 'my-domain.com',
            wsPort: 6001,
            wssPort: 6001,
            encrypted: true,
            forceTLS: false,
            enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
            authEndpoint: 'https://my-domain.com/broadcasting/auth',
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: authToken,
                },
            },
        });

        const channel = echo.private(channelUri);
        channel.subscribed(() => {
            console.log("connected");
        }).listen(eventName, (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        }).error((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, []);
```

If I change my channel URI to a public one, it connects and I can listen to events without problems. But, using the same configuration for a private channel, I can not connect. I got the following error:

```
{"error": "Unable to retrieve auth string from channel-authorization endpoint - received status: 403 from https://my-domain.com/broadcasting/auth. Clients must be authorized to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/", "status": 403, "type": "AuthError"}
```

I am sending my Bearer token in Authorization like this: "Bearer ${token}" and it works for HTTP requests, it is not expired.

Other stuff tried:
-CORS configuration
-SSL is configured, web app is working.

Any suggestions that I could try? Thanks a lot.

More info:
-PHP 8.1
-Laravel 10
-laravel-websockets 1.14
-Inertia

Comment: hi, laravel echo was not thought for react native. There is a specific package for react native-pusher (pusher-websocket-react-native), you should use that. it is similar to echo but to subscribe to private channels you cannot use the authEndpoint but the onAuthorizer callback where you will manually make the post call to https://my-domain.com/broadcasting/auth.

Comment: @suxgri thanks. Do you have any code example for this? I could not find any example on how to authenticate and connect to a private channel.

Comment: sorry i forgot to reply i ll post soon